# How could I insert records without deleting previous records in using tpt streams?

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to load data from flat file to Teradata using tpt stream16 without checking truncate target option but records getting deleted before inserting new records, I want to insert records to target without checking any condition.

Please any one help to overcome this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "truncate target" option? AFAIK there's no option to truncate a table in TPT Stream operator. Can you show your script?

Comment: Truncate table option will be there to delete previous records

Comment: I repeat, there's no option in TPT Stream to truncate a table. Of course there might be an additional step within the TPT script to do so.